# C Making the First Letter Uppercase

Tags: c, uppercase

I wanted to write a code which makes a uppercase of first letter of string 1 and 3 and printing those.

1. I tried the code below this but compiler gives **İNVALİD CONVERSİON OF CHAR TO İNT**
2. What is wrong  with this code should i try with strlen and for loop?
   This is code;

   ```
   int main()
   { 
     char str1[] = "elektrik";
     char str2[] = "ve";
     char str3[] = "elektronik";

     str1 = toupper(str1);
     str3 = toupper(str3);
     printf("%s %s %s",str1,str2,str3);
     getch();

     return 0;

   }
   ```

Comment: I included stdio,ctype,and conio libraries.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need

```
*str1 = toupper(*str1);
```

...

Asssuming that `str1` is a pointer to char (and include the appropriate header files)

Comment: Thanks it solved but why do ı have to use pointer?I am new and didn't understand this

Comment: Alternately, `str1[0] = toupper(str1[0]);`, which may be easier for newbies to understand than pointer notation.

Comment: Why *str1 = toupper(*str1); didn't make whole string uppercase?Is the *str makes operation only first character of array?

Comment: @user1944312 Because `toupper()` takes a single character and returns a possibly modified version of that character. It does not process an entire string. If you want that, a `for` loop to process every character in the string should be pretty simple..